# return char array function error

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it a good idea to return “ const char * ” from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514539/is-it-a-good-idea-to-return-const-char-from-a-function)
>   [how to return char array in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769998/how-to-return-char-array-in-c)

What is wrong with this return? I'm trying to return the current path using the following function but it doesn't seems to be correct:

Please Not: I need an char return not string.

```
char* getINIfile(void)
{
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    string::size_type pos = string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    string path = string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos) + "\\setup.ini";

    char *ini_local= (char*)path.c_str();

    printf(ini_local); // so far output OK!

    return ini_local;
}

main
{
    printf(getINIfile()); // output Not OK! 

    char mybuffer[200];
    GetPrivateProfileStringA( "files","DLL","0",  mybuffer,200, getINIfile());
    printf(mybuffer);

}
```

Comment: Why in the world... are you combining C++ and C in such a wretched fashion? Either use C and use the proper methods, or use C++ and stay away from character arrays. We have `std::string` for a reason.

Comment: I removed the C tag as this is not C (no matter how hard you try).  There is also a fundamental misunderstanding here; you cannot return arrays from functions.  A pointer is not an array.

Comment: Also, just thought I'd point out, you're using `printf` unformatted. See a nice security vulnerability: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning an address that goes out of scope when the function exits, and so it's no longer valid: `std::string path` is local to the function `getINIFile` and so it's invalid after the function exits, as is the address that you get from `path.c_str()`.

In this case you can just return the `std::string` from your function. If you *really* need a C string later, you can use `c_str()` then:

```
std::string getINIfile(void)
{
    //...

    return path;
}


int main()
{
    string path = getINIFile();

    // do something with path.c_str():
    const char *cPath = path.c_str();
}
```

Given your code I can't think of any reason that you must have a `char*` return, but if so you'll need to allocate a buffer on the heap:

```
char *getINIfile(void)
{
    char *buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    string::size_type pos = string(buffer).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    string path = string(buffer).substr( 0, pos) + "\\setup.ini";

    char *ini_local = new[path.size()];
    strncpy(ini_local, path.c_str(), path.size());

    printf(ini_local); // so far output OK!

    return ini_local;
}
```

But this is a **really awful mix** of standard C strings and `std::string`: just using `string` to manipulate the path and passing around `char*` everywhere else.

Using only standard C, replacing `find_last_of` with [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) - note the lack of error handling:

```
char *getINIfile(void)
{
    char *buffer = new[MAX_PATH];
    char *pos = NULL;
    char *ini_local = NULL;

    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    pos = strrchr(buffer, "\\/");
    // check for and handle pos == NULL

    buffer[pos] = '\0';

    strncat(buffer, "\\setup.ini", MAX_PATH - strlen(buffer));

    printf(buffer);

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: well, I need an char array return .this way still return a string which i had in first place.

Comment: @Power-Mosfet you can get the `const char*` from the returned string. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

path goes out of scope at the end of the function and you are returning an internal pointer in that out of scope object. try returning an std::string instead

```
std::string getINIfile(void)
{
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    string::size_type pos = string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    string path = string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos) + "\\setup.ini";

    char *ini_local= (char*)path.c_str();

    printf(ini_local); // so far output OK!

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is returning a pointer to a local variable, which goes out of scope, leaving you with a dangling pointer. Why not just return an `std::string` by value?

```
std::string getINIfile() {
   ....
   return path;
}
```

Then you can just use the string's underlying `char*` on the caller side:

```
const std::string s = getINIfile();
const char* c = s.c_str();
```