# Converting std::string to const char*, getting errors

Tags: c++, string, types

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
const char* numberToString(T number) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.c_str();
}

int main() {
    printf(numberToString(123));
    return 0;
}
```

My error:

```
1>d:\programming\euler\problem 4\problem 4\problem 4\source.cpp(8): error C2039: 'c_str' : is not a member of 'std::basic_ostringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>          d:\programming\euler\problem 4\problem 4\problem 4\source.cpp(26) : see reference to function template instantiation 'const char *numberToString<int>(T)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream

Comment: You cant get the `const char*` ( c_str() ) from a temporary string. Once you return from the numberToString your `stringstream` will be destroyed and its underlying `std::string` will be destroyed also. When you invoke `c_str()` it will return a pointer to something that is valid only through the `std::string` life. I suggest working with `std::string`, since it is a object (not a pointer) it will be copied when needed.

Comment: FYI, the standard library offers this functionality, there's no need to write a function for it. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: You read the documentation, hein? ...

Answer (score 7):

`c_str` is a member of `std::string`, not `ostringstream`. If you want to get a `string` out of the stream, use `str()`. Note, however, that returning a `const char*` from that `string` is wrong - the `string` will go out of scope before you can use the `const char*`. Therefore, have your function return a `string` (or have it get a buffer to write to):

```
template <typename T>
std::string numberToString(T number) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`c_str()` does not exist for `std::ostringstream`.  What you meant was:

```
template <typename T>
const char* numberToString(T number) 
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str().c_str();
}
```

After you make that change, you will have another problem:  you will be returning a pointer to a buffer that was just destroyed.  To fix that, you should return a `std::string`:

```
template <typename T>
std::string numberToString(T number) 
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Which you can do with [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) already, so it is really pointless to write your own function.

Comment: It isn't pointless if you don't have a C++11 compiler, and many people do not.  However, it is a nice recommendation for people who do have a c++11 compiler.

Comment: @shawn1874 Fair enough ... though, at this point, all the old compilers should be phasing out quickly.  Hell, C++14 is in its final stages of being approved.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `c_str()` is the member function of `std::string` which returns a `const char*`.

To get the underlying string of  a strinstream, you must use [`str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str).

The error was pretty much self explanatory:

> error C2039: 'c_str' : is not a member of 'std::basic_ostringstream

Note however that you're returning a pointer to something (the underlying data of the temporary string returned by `str()`) that will not exist after the return statement (i.e. in the calling code) and that manipulating that pointer will quite sureley end up in undefined behavior.

As you are in C++, you could rather return the `std::string` directly, and output it with

```
std::cout << numberToString(123);
```

which would be safer.

Comment: It won't be a pointer to the stream's internal data, `str()` returns a copy of the string contained within the stream. Regardless, it will still be a pointer to a temporary that will be destroyed at the end of that expression.

Comment: @Praetorian Right! Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do:

```
template <typename T>
std::string numberToString(T number) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << numberToString(123);
    return 0;
}
```

To get the underlying `std::string` in `std::ostringstream`, and then the resulting c-style string in `std::string`. As others have pointed out, the pointer returned by `c_str` goes out of scope, and therefore you must copy it to a buffer or to another `std::string`. If you insist on using `printf`, then use `c_str` on the function call:

```
printf("%s", numberToString(123).c_str());
```

For more information, see [Is it a good idea to return " const char * " from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514539/is-it-a-good-idea-to-return-const-char-from-a-function)

> Depending on what somestlstring is and what is being done there.
>
> If it is a local variable you are returning a pointer into memory that
>   is being released when GetSomeString completes, so it is a dangling
>   pointer and an error.
>
> It all boils down to the lifetime of somestlstring and the operations
>   you perform on it. The pointer returned by .c_str() is guaranteed to
>   be valid only up to the next mutating operation in the string. So if
>   something changes somestlstring from the call to .c_str() and before s
>   is constructed you will be in undefined behavior land.

However, you can simply use `std::to_string`.

```
std::string s = std::to_string(123);
```

Comment: I did that, but now my program isn't outputting anything. What's wrong?

Comment: Why do you need that `temp` for? Just go ahead and `return ss.str()`. Or at least do `temp = ss.str()`. Your wasting time for nothing creating a `string`, getting its internal buffer and constructing yet another `string`.