# Why returning a const char * from function is not a good idea?

Tags: c++, string, return-value, c-strings

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514539/is-it-a-good-idea-to-return-const-char-from-a-function) about returning const char * from function.

But I have tried it out with the following codes, it looks like everything works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const char * tocstring(){
    string str = "abcd";
    return str.c_str();
}

int main(){
    const char * p = tocstring();
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it will output `abcd` as what I want. Any idea about this?

Comment: I can't explain it as well as [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)

Answer (score 2):

> it will output abcd as what I want. Any idea about this?

The function `tocstring` returns a pointer being held by the automatic variable `str`. The pointer is invalid after the function returns. Your program is subject to undefined behavior. Unfortunately, *seemingly* sane behavior is a form of undefined behavior.

Comment: I have put undefined behavior through stress tests and it is still sane, yet still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You were lucky. `tocstring` is returning a pointer to memory that has already been freed so this is undefined behavior.

Comment: lucky or unlucky? I wish it failed first time than surprising me later.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char * tocstring(){                                                                         
    string str = "abcd";                                                                        
    return str.c_str();                                                                          
}
```

Here `str` is a local variable. Once it goes out of scope, you should not point it to anymore. It is an UB.